# Авторизация ssh без пароля и публичного ключа

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh

Подскажите как настроить авторизацию openssh без пароля и публичного ключа, то есть чтобы при подключении сразу проходила авторизация.

Comment: **PasswordAuthentication no**; **PubkeyAuthentication no**

Comment: А чем же вы тогда собрались авторизоваться?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, в $ man useradd написано, что максимальная длина имени пользователя — 32 символа (подразумевается ascii, разумеется). если брать случайную комбинацию, то угадать (перебором) нужное имя будет достаточно проблематично. // ну и вообще openssh поддерживает ещё несколько типов авторизации (помимо интерактивного ввода и открытого ключа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в конфигурации программы *sshd* (файл `sshd_config`) указываете

```
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
```

и перезапускаете *sshd* (способ зависит от операционной системы).

после этого, если у пользователя действительно пустой пароль, *sshd* позволит подключиться без ввода пароля.

демонстрация для posix-совместимой операционной системы:

```
$ docker run --rm debian:10 sh -c '{ \
  apt-get -yq update && \
  apt-get -yq install openssh-server && \
  sed -i "s/^#PermitEmptyPasswords.*/PermitEmptyPasswords yes/" /etc/ssh/sshd_config && \
  /etc/init.d/ssh start && \
  useradd -m user_without_password && \
  echo user_without_password:U6aMy0wojraho | chpasswd -e; } >/dev/null 2>&1 && \
  ssh -o checkhostip=no -o stricthostkeychecking=no user_without_password@localhost whoami'
```

результатом (после пары-тройки минут ожидания, пока пакеты установятся) будет вывод сообщения от программы whoami, выполненной от имени пользователя без пароля:

```
user_without_password
```

Comment: Этот вариант работает, но есть другой способ? У меня openssh сервер на windows server, он не позволяет установить пустой пароль для пользователя

Comment: https://www.yandex.ru/search/?text=windows%20задать%20пустой%20пароль

Comment: Как с вами можно связаться, чтобы задать ещё пару вопросов?

Comment: ssh всё-равно просит пароль, странно

Comment: я вам ничем не помогу, потому что ms/windows я вообще не пользуюсь и в ней не разбираюсь: слишком сложная для меня операционная система. только пояндексить/погуглить могу с вами за компанию. «windows openssh PermitEmptyPasswords» — рапортуют, что всё в порядке после необходимых манипуляций с реестром: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/659

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало! Вы лучший)