# SSH с пустым паролем

Tags: windows, ssh

Я создал ssh сервер на компьютере с Windows, пароля на компьютере нету, но при этом при авторизации у меня просит пароль, если я нажму enter меня не авторизируют.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Cредствами чего вы создали SSH сервер, если это OpenSSH то проверьте конфиг вот тут %programdata%\ssh\sshd_config.

Comment: Вместо использования пустого пароля (это небезопасно!) лучше настройте вход по ssh-ключу

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Авторизация ssh без пароля и публичного ключа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1276616/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-ssh-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно PermitEmptyPasswords поставить yes в sshd_config